# Jquery add as many spans as it takes to fill a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML div
`

```
<div class="words_padding">

</div>
```

That is 800px and i have got this jquery array

```
var words=["thing","my","low","life","that","repeat","his","meaning","if","she","he","never","tell","part","tubes","how","should","come","off","on","it","about","me","and","do","same","put","country","math","like"];
```

I want to fill that div with as many spans as that div can take without getting out of borders.
I have tried doing it with for like this

```
    for (var i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
        $('.words_padding').append("<span class=\"words_totp\">"+words[Math.floor((Math.random() * words.length))]+"</span>");
    }
```

But some words are longer than other ones so it goes out of borders
Jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/2yxvg5ye/2/

Comment: I don't see how 8 words that short would fill 800px wide unless your font size is ridiculously huge. Do you have a working example of this you can show us?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it is pretty big,`38px' and also has padding from both sides `10px`.I am working on jsfiddle now

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but the easiest way *by far* would be to give the container `overflow: hidden` and set it to the height of one line of text: https://jsfiddle.net/2yxvg5ye/3/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you for the solution,but i am not looking for the easiest way,i am looking for the most effective one

Comment: Well, this could well be that answer too, it just depends on how you want the UI to look.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan like this https://10fastfingers.com/typing-test/english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is simple enough.. The JS is as follows:

```
var words=["thing","my","low","life","that","repeat","his","meaning","if","she","he","never","tell","part","tubes","how","should","come","off","on","it","about","me","and","do","same","put","country","math","like"];
$('body').on('click', '.Start_tp', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $newWord, $wrapper = $('.words_padding'), canLoop = true, totalWidthsUsed = 0;
    while (canLoop) {
        $newWord = $("<span class=\"words_totp\">"+words[Math.floor((Math.random() * words.length))]+"</span>");
        $wrapper.append($newWord);
        $newWord = $wrapper.find('.words_totp').last();
        totalWidthsUsed += $newWord.outerWidth();
        if(totalWidthsUsed > 800) {
           $newWord.remove();
           canLoop = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2yxvg5ye/4/

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I propose:

```
<div class="words_padding" style="width: 800px;">

</div>

<div style="display: none;" id="hid"></div>
```

The div `#hid` is a tool for the script to come, hence its `display: none;`.

```
var words=["thing","my","low","life","that","repeat","his","meaning","if","she","he","never","tell","part","tubes","how","should","come","off","on","it","about","me","and","do","same","put","country","math","like"];


$(".words_padding").append("<span class=\"words_totp\">"+ w +"</span>");
var aux=1;
while (aux==1){
    var w = words[Math.floor((Math.random() * words.length))];
    $("#hid").append("<span class=\"words_totp\">"+ w +"</span>");       if($(".words_totp").last().position().left+$(".words_totp").last().outerWidth()+$("#hid").find(">:first-child").outerWidth()<=800){
        $(".words_padding").append($("#hid")[0]);
        $("hid").empty();
    }else{
        aux=0;
    }   
}
```

Works for me! Not the cleanest way, but seems to do the job. Let me know if you have questions :)

Comment: it gives me an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined` because of  `$(".words_totp").last().position().left`

Comment: just made a test, working fine for me. Sorry I don't know how to help :/ (and I change one line of the script above: I passed the initialization of the div outside of the while loop)

Answer (score 0):

I got close, but for the life of me can't figure out why this takes two clicks of the button to work. That being said, if you can solve that issue, then you should be good to go.

What this does is call a function to randomize the list of words, then appends all of them to the div, but they default to `display:none;`

It then goes through all the `span` elements added and does the math to see if the width is less than the container. If it is, then it will `fadeIn()` a span element, until the max width is reached.

```js
 var words = ["thing", "my", "low", "life", "that", "repeat", "his", "meaning", "if", "she", "he", "never", "tell", "part", "tubes", "how", "should", "come", "off", "on", "it", "about", "me", "and", "do", "same", "put", "country", "math", "like"];

 function shuffle(array) {
   var currentIndex = array.length,
     temporaryValue, randomIndex;

   // While there remain elements to shuffle...
   while (0 !== currentIndex) {

     // Pick a remaining element...
     randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
     currentIndex -= 1;

     // And swap it with the current element.
     temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
     array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
     array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
   }

   return array;
 }
 $('body').on('click', '.Start_tp', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   words = shuffle(words);
   var maxWidth = $('.words_padding').width();
   var width = 0;

   $(words).each(function(i) {
     $('.words_padding').append("<span class=\"words_totp\" style='display:none;'>" + words[i] + "</span>");
     $('.words_padding span').each(function() {
       width = width + $(this).outerWidth();
       if (width < maxWidth) {
         $(this).fadeIn();
       }
     });

   });
 });
```

```css
.words_totp {
  font-size: 38px;
  color: gray;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.words_padding {
  word-break: break-word;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: white;
  width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  left: 25px;
  height: 70px;
}

.Start_tp {
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 0;
  background: #03a9f4;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="words_padding"></div>
<input type="button" class="Start_tp" value="Start">
```

Here is a fiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/8k44gvrm/1/